# Is it possible to customize an input field for amounts with +- buttons?

Tags: jquery, css, forms

Is it possible with jQuery & CSS to design a input field like that?

[image: Amount]

I am not sure where to start, any help highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are usually called "Spinners", e.g. from google http://btburnett.com/spinner/example/example.html

Comment: didnt know how they are called, great thanks i found also that jQuery is going to implement it in their 1.9 version:
http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/spinner/default.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's simple way based on jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/acodesmith/aykZs/3/

The buttons aren't pratical, just showing what can be done. The importat part is the parent div.step .

EDIT:
Updated Buttons 
http://jsfiddle.net/EK9vA/

Comment: Lovely code. I (js)fiddled about with the buttons. You can see the results [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EK9vA/).

Comment: You're both welcome. I stripped down the code a bit more and came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hLRhU/).

Answer (score 2):

With HTML 5 some browser support this:

```
<input type="number" name="points" step="1" />
```

See here for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gsk4f/ (Chrome or Opera)

This is a new HTML 5 attribute and is not [supported](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_step.asp) by all browser

Comment: that is awesome but kinda limited at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

this is a great plugin!!

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/numerictextbox/index.html

Comment: looks great but adding another whole Javascript Framework just for this small thing seems not really practical, maybe there is some kind of jQuery plugin/extension

Comment: when you download it, you have every functionality separated in differents "js" files, so you add only what you want. for example only this plugin sizes 6KB

Comment: ah cool, but i also found a jquery one: http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/spinner/default.html