# jquery input number

Tags: jquery, html, types, input, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to customize an input field for amounts with +- buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006782/is-it-possible-to-customize-an-input-field-for-amounts-with-buttons)

how to make + (plus) and - (minus) value buttons for

`<input type="number" class="numbertype" value="10">` ?

I think it's possible to do with jQuery or maybe simple javascipt, but i don't know how..

I want do something like this :

[image: Input tyoe number with + and -]

when you push on + button, value will be bigger for 1 (0,12,3,4,5,6.... 10000)

when you push on - button, value will be smaller for 1 (10,9,8,7,6,5,4... 0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#minus,#plus").click(function(){
    var value = parseInt($(".numbertype").val(), 10);
    $(".numbertype").val(value + $(this).is("#minus") ? -1 : 1);
});
```

---

I just wanted to see how to do it myself. Here's a toggle that will keep going on mouse down:

```
var i = null;
var d = 0;
var $numbertype = null;

function ToggleValue() {
    $numbertype.val(parseInt($numbertype.val(), 10) + d);
}

$(function() {
    $numbertype = $(".numbertype");

    $("#minus,#plus").mousedown(function() {
        d = $(this).is("#minus") ? -1 : 1;
        i = setInterval(ToggleValue, 100);
    });

    $("#minus,#plus").on("mouseup mouseout", function() {
        clearInterval(i);
    });
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/M4BAt/5/

Comment: don't forget to pass the radix! i fixed that for you hunter!

Comment: actually that is wrong. You'd have to use the operators "++" and "--" before the variable: `$("numbertype").val(++value)`

Comment: yeah, caught that before you posted

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#plus_but').click(function(){

        var val = $('.numbertype').val();

        var new_val = parseInt($('.numbertype').val(),10) + 1 ;

       $('.numbertype').val(new_val); 

});


$('#minus_but').click(function(){

        var val = $('.numbertype').val();

        var new_val = parseInt($('.numbertype').val(),10) - 1 ;

       $('.numbertype').val(new_val); 

});
```

Comment: @Daniel you're like the Johnny Appleseed of parseInt() radix parameters

Answer (score 1):

If you substitute the images you want for the plus/minus buttons, this would work:

```
<span class="plusminusunit">
    <span class="minus">-</span> 
    <input type="number" class="numbertype" value="10">
    <span class="plus">+</span>
</span>

$(".plus").click(function() {
    var item = $(this).closest(".plusminusunit").find("input");
    item.val(Number(item.val()) + 1); 
});
$(".minus").click(function() {
    var item = $(this).closest(".plusminusunit").find("input");
    item.val(Number(item.val()) - 1); 
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/FxEv3/

With images, the HTML would look like this (using your image URLs):

```
<span class="plusminusunit">
    <img class="minus" src="http://lt.tonybet.com/assets/shared/mikro_tv-50ee396d59d5c38f979ad3fd93578f4f.png"> 
    <input type="number" class="numbertype" value="10">
    <img class="plus" src="http://lt.tonybet.com/assets/shared/mikro_tv-50ee396d59d5c38f979ad3fd93578f4f.png">
</span>
```

Comment: i tryed this, but it's nor working..

Comment: @RobertasPalinskis - What did you try because it works fine in the jsFiddle?

Comment: look here http://pastebin.com/58T4Mw5b

Comment: Putting the image inside a span made the `.parent()` reference get the wrong parent.  You can either change the HTML to not have the img inside the extra span or you can change to what I've edited my answer to now that puts a class on the container and uses `.closest()` instead of `.parent()` to get the top of the container regardless of whether there is an extra span or not.  I've offered both choices in my edited answer.

Comment: i don't know, why, but i jsfiddle it's working, but in my html not..

Comment: @RobertasPalinskis - You will also need to move your jQuery code inside a `$(document).ready()` function because you are trying to set the event handlers before the DOM has been loaded.  The jsFiddle does that for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the kendo.iu it has predefined control satisfying your wishes even more.It is very easy to implement and works great. I have already used it. No complains.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/numerictextbox/index.html